# Is it possible to create a static library directly using 'gcc' command?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

To create a static library, in general, we follow the 2-step method. First, we create object files for each source file using the '**gcc**' command. Second, We will bundle all the object files using the '**ar**' command.

I know 'gcc' and 'ar' are two separate components. But, **I would like to get the confirmation on whether it is possible to create a static library in a single step using the 'gcc' command?**
If yes, Could anyone suggest how we can do that?

Note: This question is not related to how to create a static library. This question is purely to get confirmation. I referred gcc manual entry [page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I would say simplified approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create the archive library using `gcc` only.

An approximation to the idea of a static library using GCC only is to create a relocatable object file containing all the component files:

```
gcc -r -o libobject.o object1.o object2.o object3.o
```

This creates a single object file, `libobject.o`, that contains all the object code from the list of object files (`object1.o`, `object2.o`, `object3.o`).  It can be linked with any code that uses any of the functions to create an executable.

```
gcc -o program program.o libobject.o
```

Note that you must supply the path to the composite object file on the linker command line — it won't be found using a library search.

However, this is only an approximation to a static library because with a library, only the object files that provide functions used are linked into the executable, whereas with a composite object file like `libobject.o`, all the code in all the object files is always linked into the executable.  You rarely use every single function provided by a library in a single program.